# swfobject 2 won't load SWF only with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I have the too common issue of a javascript snippet working on every browser except IE (using the version shipped with Windows 7, Flash explicitly installed and double checked today).
In order to avoid this kind of issue I already chose to use the latest SWFObject.js but apparently it's not enough. Please feel free to check yourself out at:

[A wiki I am installing](http://www.fleurworld.com/wiki/)

Notice you'll see script data-cfasync statements to block Cloudflare's JS optimization. They don't affect the outcome (I tested with and without them and disabled CF's RocketLoader).

Here are some attempts of mine:

The first example works on all browsers except IE:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars = {};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {};
  attributes.id = "fwbanner-id";
  attributes.class = "fwbanner-class";
  swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.fleurworld.com/static/media/images/banners/fw_wk_banner_en.swf", "fwbanner-div", "850", "85", "9.0.0", "/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

The second example makes use of a suggestion I read on Stack Overflow, that is to get the element ID instead of explicitly indicating it. It still works on all browsers except IE.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars = {};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {};
  attributes.id = document.getElementById("fwbanner-id");
  attributes.class = "fwbanner-class";
  swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.fleurworld.com/static/media/images/banners/fw_wk_banner_en.swf", "fwbanner-div", "850", "85", "9.0.0", "/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

This third snippets won't work at all (in any browser): document.getElementById("fwbanner-id") in IE returns null but putting on onload() still won't fix it. I wanted to see if delaying the element ID retrieval till the DOM was loaded would help. It looks like it doesn't.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ShowBanner() {
  var flashvars = {};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {};
  attributes.id = document.getElementById("fwbanner-id");
  attributes.class = "fwbanner-class";
  swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.fleurworld.com/static/media/images/banners/fw_wk_banner_en.swf", "fwbanner-div", "850", "85", "9.0.0", "/wiki/extensions/fwbanner/js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
}
</script>
```

Any help or directions would be really appreciated!